# If you buy dark elixir without a dark elixir storage what happens

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have a level 7 town hall and I would like to get a  barbarian king. However, I don't have a dark elixir storage. What would happen if I buy a King ? I'm affraid to lose my gem so any advice would be great thanks.

Comment: I dont play the game but why the downvotes ?

Answer (score 4):

You cant get the king without the dark storage. I just tried and it wouldnt let me spend my gems.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have dark elixir storage, you cannot store dark elixir. So if you buy dark elixir with gems, (which shouldn't even be possible) they would be lost.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy the dark elixir with real money in the game, by clicking on a pack and purchasing it in the shop.If you have observed carefully, if you have clicked on info button, you can clearly see at the bottom - "NO STORAGE LIMITS". If you are a TH-7 one, by default on upgrading to TH-7 you can store a maximum of 2500 Dark Elixir. You can't store more than 2500 Dark Elixir unless you have bought a storage for it, if you haven't bought any pack.So, you can buy the Barbarian King, if you have enough dark elixir(10000 dark elixir) in your storage.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you buy dark elixir without having dark elixir storage, you will lose your gems and not get any dark elixir.

Answer (score 1):

You need a dark elixir storage, otherwise you will lose your dark elixir.

Answer (score 1):

If you try, the gems will be lost no matter what, even if you have a drill. You have to be able to hold enough to take it.

Answer (score 1):

Without a dark elixir storage you will only be able to buy the small amount that your town hall can store. You cannot buy more than that amount because of how purchasing of resources with gems operates (you buy a percentage of your storage available).