# Using Gems to Buy More Loot for Upgrades Even Though The Storages are Full?

Tags: clash-of-clans

For example, I have 10k dark elixir and x gems as long its enough to buy another 2.5k dark elixir so I can upgrade my Barbarian King to level two. My storage is currently at level one, which means that it can only hold 10k, which is not enough to hold the 12.5k dark elixir necessary to upgrade my Barbarian King.

So my question is, when the game asks me if I want to buy more dark elixir to have enough for the upgrade, if I do buy the remaining 2.5k dark elixir, will the game let me or will it not and ask me to upgrade my storage instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [If you buy dark elixir without a dark elixir storage what happens](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/151361/if-you-buy-dark-elixir-without-a-dark-elixir-storage-what-happens)

Comment: Buying 10,000 DE with a storage of 0 is the same principle as buying 12,500 DE with a storage of 10,000. **The only problem is that the other answer, like this one has no definite answer.**

Comment: If you dont even have any dark elixir, you can't even buy any DE anyways @aytimothy

Comment: Dammit, just upgraded my DE storage to lv2 so I can't test this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was unable to find sources on the internet to test this, but with personal tests I can prove that you cannot purchase more resources than your storages.

First the store can only allow you buy % of your total storage:
[image]
Secondly, when you try to purchase more loot than what you have it will say `Build Or Upgrade Existing <Type of Storage> Storages!`

[image]

Comment: Bounty coming your way [in about 5 days]. I'll just leave it for exposure for upvotes first.

Comment: And my accept...

Answer (score 0):

### You can not.

---

You can only buy the loot that you can hold in your storages.
Because you have to have the loot before you can use it.
Lets say I have a Lv.1 D.Elixer Storage (like yourself),  it can only hold 10K D.Elixer.  I'd have to have 12,500 Dark Elixer before upgrading my Barb. King.  My punny 10K limit can not handle the true power of an extra 2.5K D.Elixer.

---

Long Story Short you have to upgrade you're storage before you can upgrade you're king to level 2.

---

- Clash on!

Comment: Do you have a source or is this from experience?

Comment: only Personal Experience... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't — and even if you didn't buy the dark and upgraded the king instead and you were short of dark and tried to gem it, it still won't work. You must upgrade your storage.

Answer (score 0):

## Update: You can!

*... as of early last year.*

Supercell from time to time sells resource packs in the store. These packs are not limited by your storage limits and only limited by your wallet (and what's available).

The same applies for loot claimed from the Season Pass Bank. The max possible is 18 million, but you can overfill up to 43 million by having a full Season Bank (25 million) and an already max'd (and full) storage, without spending money (pass doesn't count) that is.